# Kusto avgif() greater than

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to do an average if a duration is over a certain amount of seconds

I can't get it working

something like this

```
| summarize Totalcount=count(),Average=avgif(round(duration/1000,2)>10.00)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `avgif()` expects two arguments. If I run what you've posted, I get:

```
avgif(): function expects 2 argument(s).
```

Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/avgif-aggfunction).

The solution could be:

```
| summarize Totalcount=count(),Average=avgif(round(duration/1000,2), round(duration/1000,2)>10.00)
```

Comment: Thanks I was getting mixed up with another function and didn't realise that